# Did the publication of ECMA-404 affect the validity of JSON texts such as '2' or '"hello"'?

Tags: json, specifications

Are the following valid JSON texts, or must their top-level value be an array or object?

```
4.0
```

```
"Hello World"
```

```
true
```

Related questions in the past, such as [What is the minimum valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json), and [Is this simple string considered valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487869/is-this-simple-string-considered-valid-json/) have concluded that they are not. This was based on the description of the JSON format in [RFC-4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), which states that:

> ### 2.  JSON Grammar
>
> A JSON text is a sequence of tokens.  The set of tokens includes six
>     structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal names.
>
> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.
>
> ```
>  JSON-text = object / array
> ```
>
> These are the six structural characters:
>
> [...]

However, the RFC-4627 status declares that it "does not specify an Internet standard of any kind". Instead, the official standard for JSON is the recently-published [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). Unlike RFC-4627, ECMA-404's description of valid JSON text does not include any requirement that it be an object or an array. For example, the section most similar to the quote above is missing that requirement:

> ### 4 JSON Text
>
> A JSON text is a sequence of tokens formed from Unicode code points that conforms to the JSON value 
>   grammar. The set of tokens includes six structural tokens, strings, numbers, and three literal name tokens.
>
> The six structural tokens:
>
> [...]

Given this new specification, are encoded non-array non-object top-level values considered valid JSON texts?

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/, because the question is the same, even though the context (date on which it was asked) is different.

Comment: As per [RFC7159](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt) _A JSON text is a serialized value_ in other words all valid JSON values are valid JSON text i.e. `false / null / true / object / array / number / string` are all valid JSON text

Comment: Deleting this post because it's kind-of a duplicate and not really relevant in 2019.

Answer (score 31):

Douglas Crockford posted a comment on [this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/118095276221607585885/posts/TN4Y2xy64Yq) which helped me start to clarify things:

> JSON is just a grammar, and the grammar includes numbers and strings. Uses of JSON must necessarily be more restrictive. RFC-4627 is one possible use, and was never intended to be the standard for JSON itself.

We cannot say that non-array non-object JSON texts are generally invalid, just that it is not valid to use them with internet media type `application/json`, per RFC-4627.

Representations of non-object non-array values are valid JSON texts per ECMA-404, which is the only currently published standard that might be identified as "the JSON specification".

However, it turns out that the IETF is likely to soon publish a replacement to RFC-4627 which will *also* be a specification of JSON. [Its latest draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-json-rfc4627bis/?include_text=1) still includes the restriction on JSON texts, but also mentions that JSON has be specified in several places and that these specifications vary slightly. The draft specifically mentions that the definition of JSON in ECMA-262 (the ECMAScript/JavaScript specification) does not share the top-level value restriction.

Therefore, the question of whether non-object non-arrays are valid JSON texts must be disambiguated:

#### Is `"hello"` a valid JSON text as specified in RFC-4627 and its successor?

No.

#### Is `"hello"` a valid JSON text as specified by ECMA-404 and ECMA-262?

Yes.

Comment: Tim Bray wrote [an informative post that explains more of the history of JSON specification](https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2014/03/05/RFC7159-JSON).

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json/22361229#22361229 which updates the definition found in RFC-7158 which *does* allow a string as the top-level JSON text. That answer also clarifies what RFC-7159 is.