# MessagePack: is there a "grammar" for valid msgpack structures?

Tags: parsing, serialization, deserialization, messagepack

The [MessagePack specification](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md) helps you to learn about the available data types and their binary representation. However, I can't find information on the "grammar" that has to be used for building valid msgpack structures (since it's not a textual but a binary format, the term "grammar" is probably not accurate). I'm especially wondering if there are any requirements regarding the "top-level" elements within a msgpack structure. It's basically a similar question to the one that occured for JSON [some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569221/did-the-publication-of-ecma-404-affect-the-validity-of-json-texts-such-as-2-or), albeit JSON's grammar is specified.

Using msgpack, is it ok to have primitive types (Int, Boolean..) at the top level, or does everything have to be encapsulated in a map/array? Is it possible to have multiple elements at the top level (e.g. two arrays, not nested, but "next to each other")?